# What are the 'foot wraps' called that many fantasy characters seem to wear

Tags: terminology

Essentially, what I am trying to find a term for a wrapping of the foot in cloth or leather, which protects the sole, yet leaves the heel, ball, and toe free.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because RPG expertise is irrelevant to answering it - see [Are campaign research questions on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1604/15469)

Comment: This question could be a better fit for [English StackExchange](https://english.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Hi EncartaDM, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. Unfortunately as written this question is off-topic here for the reasons Miniman gave. Why do you want this information? Perhaps if you are trying to solve an RPG problem you can [edit] the question to be more on topic.